# Is it normal for bluetooth devices to stop responding when CPU is too busy?

Tags: bluetooth, airport

I have MacBook Pro 13" mid 2012 with 16GB RAM and 256GB SSD, Mojave 10.14.1. my Magic Trackpad 1 and AirPods get slow when CPU is too busy, especially when cpu percentage is above 70%. My USB-wired keyboard and mouse seamlessly work even if it is too busy. I wanted to try Apple Hardware Test for more details, but it says the error code DEC400 so I can't do that. I have an appointment at Genius Bar to check for my Airport card this Friday. I am worried they refused to fix it just because my mac is too slow.

EDIT: When executing Java programs from IntelliJ IDEA, sometimes Bluetooth devices get slow but sometimes work well. Maybe some other factors makes them slow. I had the same problem when I worked on Sierra.

[image]
I've checked out from event logs from Bluetooth Explorer. I think it tells me a lot. I am not sure exactly what they indicate, though.

### What I found out from Bluetooth Explorer

- Mac drops the connection to the AirPods from some reasons. logs says the reason is 0x08. I think Google and Apple official user guide are both silent on what the reason code indicate. Some other factors somehow affect my AirPods, as well as a busy CPU.
- When the CPU is too busy, the Throughput graph goes down dramatically.
- [image]

Comment: 2012 is not slow machine, but to verfy open the Activity monitor, sort by CPU usage take a screen shot and post it here. And while at it tell us what OSX is it. Also how is your battery doing ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I always have my mac connected to power charger.

Comment: Aside of noticing that you have a number of "other" apps that might interfere, the BT is only consuming 0.2%. Hold Shift+Option and click on BT in the menu bar. Run the Debug.

Comment: you mean Debug -> Reset the Bluetooth Module?

Comment: Yes, Reset. Let me take a wild guess, it worked well before Mojave! Mojave might have some problems with your MBP mid 2012.

Comment: No, I had the same problem when I worked on Sierra. and I upgraded from it to Mojave. some other wild guess is welcome! I am going to try everything to do.

Comment: Reset doesn't fix it.

Comment: Well it was a try, so that is not the problem. I prepared answer (below) with instructions how to evaluate BT performances. Since without data on BT I can not pinpoint your problem, have fun finding it. Best would be if you could report what you found for others.

Comment: The more I used Bluetooth, the more I became convinced of the need to switch to other technologies. For some reason, Bluetooth devices are always the ones with strange and unexplainable hiccups. USB dongles suck, but I need my tech to actually *work*.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to delete all the system Bluetooth configurations and cache. Since this problem has persisted since the last OS this could be the culprit. Otherwise I wonder if TechTool or the like has a Bluetooth hardware diagnostic function.

Comment: I think it became clear that a busy CPU affects Bluetooth. Now I am going to install macOS on my extra HDD that makes Bluetooth configurations and cache clear. We'll see that bluetooth devices perform well on that environment.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can not pinpoint your BT problem ...
I suggest you try this great tool provided by Apple.

You have to download Bluetooth Explorer as part of the 'Additional Tools for Xcode' package that's available (registration required) at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

Go to that link, then search for 'Additional', and find the Additional Tools package for the latest version of Xcode (you don't actually need Xcode installed to use the Bluetooth Explorer app!).

Among other tools available, Open the Hardware Folder and select the BT Explorer.

[image]

Use it to determine your BT performance while you are running the IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I added a throughput graph. I don't still know why busy cpu affects devices.

Comment: @inherithandle https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: @inherithandle or maybe consider CPU throttle for the IntelliJ ...http://www.willnolan.com/cputhrottle/cputhrottle.html

Comment: Does the latest Macbook Pro throttle its CPU to get over the bluetooth problem, too?

Comment: and My IntelliJ IDEA and the other applications doesn't hang. bluetooth devices only stop responding.